# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'lambda_handler' was never awaited

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I am writing a lambda function in python which automates the exports of cloudwatch logs in s3 for multiple log group at a single invocation.
If I use it without await and async it gives `An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation: Resource limit exceeded.`
Another way is using async and await function it gives me the error. I am not very good with python. Any kind of help is appreciated.
My lambda code:

```py
import json
import boto3
import datetime
import os
import time
import asyncio

async def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('logs')
    days = 7
    no_of_days = int(days)
    region_name = "ap-southeast-1"
    destination_bucket = "abc"
    
    response = client.describe_log_groups(
        limit=50
    )
    
    print(response)
    
    x = list()
    
    for i in response['logGroups']:
        x.append(i['logGroupName'])

    # while "nextToken" in response:
    #     response = client.describe_log_groups(
    #         nextToken=response["nextToken"]
    #     )
    #     for i in response['logGroups']:
    #         x.append(i['logGroupName'])
    
    # print(x)
    
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    startTime = current_datetime - datetime.timedelta(days=no_of_days)
    endTime = current_datetime - datetime.timedelta(days=0)
    
    fromDate = int(startTime.timestamp() * 1000)
    toDate = int(endTime.timestamp() * 1000)

    for i in x:
        if "codebuild" not in i:
            print(i)
            await asyncio.run(export_to_s3(i,fromDate,toDate,destination_bucket))
            
    
async def export_to_s3(logGroupName1, fromTime1, to1, destination1):
        
    export_task = client.create_export_task(
            taskName = 'export_logs_to_s3',
            logGroupName = logGroupName1,
            fromTime = fromTime1,
            to = to1,
            destination = destination1,
            destinationPrefix = os.path.join(startTime.strftime('%Y{0}%m{0}%d').format(os.path.sep),logGroupName1)
        )
```

Error:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError",
  "requestId": "ca7a1113-b6a5-4ce9-a187-5867f1a91ea5",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Logs

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: ca7a1113-b6a5-4ce9-a187-5867f1a91ea5 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py:405: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'lambda_handler' was never awaited
handle_event_request(
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
END RequestId: ca7a1113-b6a5-4ce9-a187-5867f1a91ea5
REPORT RequestId: ca7a1113-b6a5-4ce9-a187-5867f1a91ea5  Duration: 6.86 ms   Billed Duration: 7 ms   Memory Size: 10240 MB   Max Memory Used: 55 MB  Init Duration: 291.92 ms

Request ID
ca7a1113-b6a5-4ce9-a187-5867f1a91ea5
```